# MultiProcessing Python not working in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
   "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\1\main.py", line 27, in <module>
       p.start()   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py",
   line 121, in start
       self._popen = self._Popen(self)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py",
   line 224, in _Popen
       return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)   File
   "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py",
   line 326, in _Popen
       return Popen(process_obj)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py",
   line 93, in _init_
       reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py",
   line 60, in dump
       ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj) pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x039E9538>: attribute lookup
   <lambda> on __main_ failed

   C:\Users\HP\Downloads\1>Traceback (most recent call last):   File
   "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File
   "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py",
   line 102, in spawn_main
       source_process = _winapi.OpenProcess( OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

""
Im trying to open multiple chromedrivers/files.py at the same time/instant.
But it shows the error.
The code is to get the sample from file.py and create multiple same files like file_1.py.....
Then run all the files that has created but is not working.

The Code is:

```
for proxy in file:
    shutil.copyfile('/home/hp/Documents/pr/proxy_project/template.py', '/home/hp/Documents/pr/proxy_project/file_{}.py'.format(i))
    file_name = "file_{}".format(i)
    file_list.append(file_name)
    with open('/home/hp/Documents/pr/proxy_project/file_{}.py'.format(i), 'r') as replicated_file:
        data = replicated_file.readlines()
    data_to_be_added = "proxy = '{}'\n".format(proxy.strip("\n"))
    data[16] = data_to_be_added
    with open('/home/hp/Documents/pr/proxy_project/file_{}.py'.format(i), 'w') as new_replicated_file:
        new_replicated_file.writelines(data)
    i += 1

for file_py in tuple(file_list):
    print("File name = {}".format(file_py))
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: __import__(file_py))
    p.start()
```

There is another file that will be replicated when this code runs

Comment: Whatever you're trying to pass to the child process is not pickleable. We'll need to see your code too, not only the error.

Comment: @AKX check right now

Comment: Why on earth are you building new files with different contents? If what you want is to use a different `proxy` value for a function, use `multiprocessing.map` with that function.

Comment: @AKX if u have twitter/whatsapp or something please tell me to help|||||||||  I want like to put +100 proxies in .txt files than from that txt file python need for each proxy to open a chrome driver than go to a certian website.
But if there is more proxies i want 100 proxy per 60 sec///100 chrome drivers per 60 sec.
I have done it but only one by one

Comment: Demanding contact info to have someone privately help with your problem isn't considered very courteous. You might have better luck asking your actual question, i.e. how to open different chromedrivers with varying proxy settings with a rate limit, as a separate question.

Comment: On Windows when using multiprocessing you __have__ to protect your main code with `if __name__==‘__main__’:` - try reading the multiprocessing documentation.

Comment: I agree with @AKX, this seems like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using multiprocessing you have to protect your main code with

```
if __name__== '__main__':
```

This is documented in the [multiprocessing programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming), specifically under "Safe importing of main module"